# Linux cmake stuck in file(GLOB) command for several hours

Tags: linux, cmake, bitbake

When I run bitbake, it gets stuck in a package's do_configure task. Debugging by printing, I found that it got stuck in 
https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blame/ae5f98a5e36da8cf3c75625ffb9a1d34aa2407cb/Modules/FindDoxygen.cmake, exactly this line:

```
file(GLOB _Doxygen_GRAPHVIZ_BIN_DIRS
  "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/Graphviz*/bin"
  "$ENV{ProgramFiles${_x86}}/Graphviz*/bin"
  )
```

Then I wrote this CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(_x86 "(x86)")
message(STATUS "Will run file GLOB...")
file(GLOB _Doxygen_GRAPHVIZ_BIN_DIRS
  "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/Graphviz*/bin"
  "$ENV{ProgramFiles${_x86}}/Graphviz*/bin"
  )
unset(_x86)
message(STATUS "file GLOB end")
```

Running with an older cmake version on RedHat Linux:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.6.1
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Will run file GLOB...
# stuck for several hours...
```

Running with a newer cmake version on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Will run file GLOB...
-- file GLOB end
...
-- Build files have been written to: xxx
# Finished in less than 1min.
```

So is `file(GLOB)` a bug in older cmake version? I searched Google, no description about this "bug" found. But it does behave differently between older/newer versions.

Comment: Does the wildcard match a lot of directories?

Comment: No, the wildcard matches nothing. The `{ProgramFiles}` path is apparently for Windows, not for Linux.

Comment: Then it certainly sounds like a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: Try stracing the cmake process to see where it is spinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake execution hangs when this code is run on Linux, as the `file()` command gets stuck on the parentheses in the path `(x86)`. When `bash` encounters parentheses, without being surrounded by single quotes, it throws the error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Thus, on the older version of CMake, the `file()` command will never return, because it uses `bash` to perform specific operations.

The more recent versions of CMake have avoided the issue by surrounding this CMake code block with a check for Windows. See the latest code [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/7046a5219893436cbe19b6973ac13fb489199601/Modules/FindDoxygen.cmake#L501):

```
if(WIN32)
    set(_x86 "(x86)")
    file(
        GLOB _Doxygen_GRAPHVIZ_BIN_DIRS
        "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/Graphviz*/bin"
        "$ENV{ProgramFiles${_x86}}/Graphviz*/bin"
    )
    unset(_x86)
else()
    set(_Doxygen_GRAPHVIZ_BIN_DIRS "")
endif()
```

Comment: Thank you. Great answer. Newer cmake requires higher gcc version to compile. Finally I decided to patch FindDoxygen.cmake file with the WIN32 condition, to work around this issue.